# strategy for id/class attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

Suppose you have a list of posts and each post has an id.

Now there can be many buttons, fields, etc to interact with this post.
(edit/delete/upvote/title .. to name a few)

I've included id in every element that is interactive and used it to reference other elements.
(e.g. when user clicks an edit button, I find textarea with the same id to change the appearance)

```
<div class='post' data-post-id='3'>
  <div class='upvote' data-post-id='3'>
    {{upvote}}
  </div>
  <div class='textarea' data-post-id='3'>
  </div>
  <div class='buttons'>
    <button class='btn-edit' data-post-id='3' />
    <button class='btn-delete' data-post-id='3' />
    <button class='btn-upvote' data-post-id='3' />
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm fairly new to javascripts and feels this awkward.
Are there better scheme (or strategy) to give identifiers to work with?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking, but you can make a selector something like button[data-post-id=3], if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simpler approarch will be like so

```
<div class='post' data-post-id='3'>
  <div class='upvote'>
    {{upvote}}
  </div>
  <div class='textarea'>
  </div>
  <div class='buttons'>
    <button class='btn-edit'  />
    <button class='btn-delete' />
    <button class='btn-upvote'/>
  </div>
</div>
```

now when the user clicks the button you can do as follows :

```
$('button').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).parents('.post').data('post-id'))
})
```

so when you apply the edit it will be like so

```
$('div[data-post-id="3"].textarea')
```

sure thing you will need to replace the "3" with the id you got from the previous function .

### edit :

as [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) said you can use closest . if you feel that parents is an over kill .

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDEL](http://jsfiddle.net/5zWx7/)**</kbd>

Comment: `closest` is more appropriate than `parents`. `parents` will search for *all* parents of the element with that class, but you're only using the closest one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in this case i doubt that there will be any other parents having the same class as `post` .

Comment: @T.J.Crowder not really convinced , but i have edited the question just to be in ht safe side :) , thank you .

Answer (score 2):

I would just put the `data-post-id` on the post's top-level `div` (with class `post`). Then, any time you need it, if your starting point is one of the elements within that `div`, just use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to find it, e.g. suppose `this` is one of the buttons. Then:

```
var postId = $(this).closest("div.post").attr("data-post-id");
```

So for instance, I assume all of these posts are in a container of some kind, which I'll call `div.container`. You can use a delegated handler for your various buttons, like so:

```
$("div.container").on("click", ".btn-edit", function() {
    var postId = $(this).closest("div.post").attr("data-post-id");
    // ...handle the edit click
});
```

---

Side note: I've used `.attr("data-post-id")` to retrieve the post ID above. You'll get a lot of people telling you to use `.data("post-id")`. While that *works*, it's overkill unless you're going to do other things with the data. The `.data` method manages data associated with the element using off-element storage managed by jQuery, and *initializes* that data from the `data-*` attributes. If your only use of the `data-*` attribute is to read it, `.data` is overkill. Mostly harmless, but overkill.

Comment: on second thought, if post has child posts, would 'closest' still work? I suspect buttons in the bottom of post could be closer to its children's div than its own div?

Comment: @eugene: If you have a post within a post, and the inner post has buttons, `closest` will find the one nearest the buttons. Given the structure you've posted, if I assume nested posts are in the `div.textarea`, that shouldn't be a problem, `closest` should find the correct post. The way `closest` works is: It looks at the element on which you call it to see if that matches, and if it doesn't it looks to the parent, then the grandparent, etc. (I say "element" for simplicity, but remember jQuery is set-based. But if your starting point is just one element as with `$(this)`, we can ignore that.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery selectors http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ to find appropriate element. For example:

$("#element") will get you element with id="element" (eg: )

in your case you can use

```
$(".btn-edit").click(function(){
// action
});
```

Comment: I'm struggling to see how this is relevant to the question.